# BottomNavigationView icons/text menu item not fitting in some devices

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Android BottomNavigationView icons/text menu item not fitting in some devices (4 items in total). On nexus 5 emulator you have to rotate in order for all items to show. It doesn't matter if you start in portrait or landscape view, icons only show when device is rotated (See images below for example)

I have tried a few physical devices that I have available for testing and it works fine on all those devices (small and big), I believe its also not working for Samsung S7/8 according to tester but can't confirm that.

[Open in Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfznv.png)

[Portrait to landscape rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgIZf.png)

[Landscape to Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iTRu.png)

[Open in landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEo0E.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation it turned out to be a different issue entirely.

I was checking a user permission variable from my server response and then removing navigation item but was only checking when activity was a new instance in onCreate which is why it was different on screen rotation.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) 
   checkUserPermissions();

private void checkUserPermissions(){
   navigation.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.navigation_pickup);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    try {
      Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
      shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
      shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
      shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);

      for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);          
        item.setShiftingMode(false);            
        item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
      }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
      Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
    }
  }
```

and add this to your `BottomNavigatoionView`

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
disableShiftMode(navigation); //add the function
navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.your_navigation_choice); // set your first icon
```